# Develop function into Taylor series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

I'm at my very first steps with sequences so please be gentle.
need to find the Taylor sequence and its region of convergence of $ f(x) = \frac{x}{2+x} $ where $ x_0 = 1 $.

I know that the sequence, $ \Sigma_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^nx^n $ converges to $ \frac{1}{1+x} $ for $ | x | < 1 $ so I thought to write the original function as $ f(x) = \frac{1}{1+2/x} = \Sigma_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n(2/x)^n $ but what I don't understand is how should I use the face that $ x_0=1$?

I didn't use it in at all and I'm not sure what's the meaning of it.

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

I presume you want the Taylor series in the form
$$f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n (x-x_0)^n
=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n (x-1)^n.$$
Then
$$f(x+1)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n x^n.$$
Now
$$f(x+1)=\frac{1+x}{3+x}=\frac{1+x}3\sum_{m=0}^\infty\left(-\frac x3\right)^n$$
etc.

Comment: Thank you for answering but can you please explain why you looked at $ f(x+1) $? how is it related to the fact that $x_0 =1$?

Answer (score 2):

To expand $f(x)$ in a neigbourhood of $x=1$ is the same as expanding $f(x+1)=\frac{x+1}{x+3}$ in a neighbourhood of the origin. Since
$$ f(x+1) = 1-\frac{2}{3+x} = 1-\frac{2}{3}\cdot\frac{1}{1+\frac{x}{3}} \stackrel{\text{GS}}{=} \frac{1}{3}-\frac{2}{3}\sum_{m\geq 1}\frac{(-1)^m}{3^m}x^m \tag{1}$$
($\text{GS}$ stands for $\text{G}$eometric $\text{S}$eries) it follows that:
$$ f(x) = \frac{1}{3}-\frac{2}{3}\sum_{m\geq 1}\frac{(-1)^m}{3^m}(x-1)^m.\tag{2} $$